# How to read conf.properties file from other class?

Tags: java

I am beginner with Selenium, I have created a class name for reading called `ReadPropertyFile`. In this class I have written a code for reading a `config.properties` file. Now i have a main class where I want to call `ReadPropertyFile` class from and their activity from which I can read the `config.properties` file.

Please help me how to do this below are the code:

ReadPropertyFile.java:

```
public class ReadPropertyFile {

    public static void main(String[] arg)throws IOException{

        // Read configuration properties file

        String projdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String propfilepath = projdir+"\\configuration\\"+"conf.properties";
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(new FileInputStream(propfilepath ));

        String url  = p.getProperty("URL");
        System.out.println(url); // It is returning me a value corresponding to key "test"
        String driverFilePath = p.getProperty("DRIVER_FILE_PATH");
        System.out.println(driverFilePath);
        String testSuite  = p.getProperty("TEST_SUITE");
        System.out.println(testSuite);
    }
}
```

MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass {

    static Properties properties= new Properties();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ReadPropertyFile readConfigFile= new ReadPropertyFile();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in method if it is working

```
public class ReadPropertyFile {

 public Properties  loadPropertiess() throws IOException{

// Read configuration properties file

   String projdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
   String propfilepath = projdir+"\\configuration\\"+"conf.properties";
   Properties p = new Properties();
 p.load(new FileInputStream(propfilepath ));

   String url  = p.getProperty("URL");
  System.out.println(url); // It is returning me a value corresponding to key "test"
  String driverFilePath = p.getProperty("DRIVER_FILE_PATH");
  System.out.println(driverFilePath);
  String testSuite  = p.getProperty("TEST_SUITE");
   System.out.println(testSuite);
   return p;
} }
```

then call this method on you main class

```
public class MainClass {

  static Properties properties= null;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

  ReadPropertyFile readConfigFile= new ReadPropertyFile();

   properties = readConfigFile.loadPropertiess();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your config Reader in a class Methode.

And you can only use 'main' only once at Time.

```
  public class ReadPropertyFile{

           public void readFile(){

                // read config
```